# How do I remove this connector to my bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, plumbing-fixture

[image]

I have a small leak where this (marvel?) connector is meeting the drain pipe coming in from the wall. I've tried everything I can to get this off but I am unable to. Is this glued? The replacement I got says it's a compression fit.

My last idea, (which is probably dumb) is to get a hacksaw and score the connector at 12,3,6 and 9 o'clock to hopefully take it off in pieces. I'm worried I'll damage the drain pipe coming into the house. What are my options?

Comment: It *looks* to be solvent-welded, and if you were to cut it off, is there enough pipe left to make a new connection? Have you tried teflon tape to seal the leak?

Comment: If you cut off the current solvent-welded part flush with the back of the wider part, and then remove the wall escutcheon (perhaps replacing it with a thin flat plate) you should have enough pipe end length to solvent weld on whatever kind of fitting you like.

Comment: @Armand,  Copy that comment and place it as an answer.  It is the best advice.

Comment: I assume the leak is at the back of the threaded fitting?  Also, it's it really the drain pipe going *into* the wall?

Answer (score 1):

It is PVC and glued.

Your options are to cut and remove the current coupler and replace with an inside coupler (easiest), or remove and work from the other side of the wall.

Obviously depends on your skill/comfort level. Easy is the inside coupler.

Answer (score 0):

If you cut off the current solvent-welded part flush with the back of the wider part, and then remove the wall escutcheon (perhaps replacing it with a thin flat plate) you should have enough pipe end length to solvent weld on whatever kind of fitting you like.